# How to set AppendCheckItem to "check" by default in wxwidgets?

Tags: c++, user-interface, checkbox, menu, wxwidgets

I have a drop down menu "menu" for which I want to add a check item which should be checked by default.
How can I do the same in wxwidgets in C++?

```
check_option = menu->AppendCheckItem(CHECK_ID, wxT("Check"));
```

Comment: Call `check_option->Check( true );`

Comment: is it the only way? can't we supply any arguments to it?

Comment: What's wrong with that way, and how would supplying arguments be better?

Comment: one liner would reduce the LOC

Comment: Just make your own helper function if you're optimizing for LOC.

Comment: So you want me to add another 5 lines for one line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussion,

In wxwidgets we don't have a one liner way to do the same. There is no other arguments that `AppendCheckItem` accepts. Hence we need to call the check function to do the same.

```
check_option->Check(true);
```